# Set Firewall to allow access to ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, windows-firewall

I have two computers on the same LAN (via router).  One computer has an ASP.NET application installed.  I can run this application from the 2nd computer only if I set the Windows Firewall for Public Networks OFF.  I don't want to set the Firewall OFF for any application but only for this particular ASP.NET app.  How do I do it? Where do I specify in the Firewall to allow just one ASP.NET app?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Allow inbound port 80 and 443?

Answer (score 0):

Is it application hosted in IIS or is it self hosted?
Can you access it via a web browser

```
    http://localhost/<your_application_Name>
```

should be port 80 then.

You might need to run command promt and "netstat -a" to find the port otherwise.
If you know the port add the inbound rule for it in the firewall.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  The application is hosted in IIS.  So I will look at the Firewall on how to port 80 and/or 443 to the inbound rule.

Comment: you only need 443 if your application is accessible via SSL, i.e. if you can access it like https://....

Comment: My application does not use SSL. So port 80 is all I need. However, I am wondering, if I open port 80 to inbound, can someone from outside of my local area network (that is, from Internet) access the application?

Comment: Your router probably has a firewall set up. If you don't want this application being accessed from internet, just make sure your LAN router doesn't open port 80.

Comment: Thank you, Aleksey.  I will look into the router setting before I open this port. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Firewall, make sure that the rule 'World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In) is turned on.  This worked for me.